# CATransition to other view works, crashes on transition back

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, catransition

I am using this code to transition from the current view to another and it works. The problem is that when I try to return to the current view the app crashes.

This is the code I use to pass from the current view to the new one:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];

transition.duration = 0.75;
// using the ease in/out timing function
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;

transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;

transition.delegate = self;

// Next add it to the containerView's layer. This will perform the transition based on how we change its contents.
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

// Here we hide view1, and show view2, which will cause Core Animation to animate view1 away and view2 in.

self.view.hidden = YES;

MyMessages *info1=[[MyMessages alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMessages" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:info1.view];

info1.view.hidden = NO;
self.view.hidden = NO;
```

I try to return using this code:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];

transition.duration = 0.75;
// using the ease in/out timing function
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;

transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;

transition.delegate = self;

// Next add it to the containerView's layer. This will perform the transition based on how we change its contents.
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

// Here we hide view1, and show view2, which will cause Core Animation to animate view1 away and view2 in.
self.view.hidden = YES;

FirstViewController *info1=[[  FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:info1.view];

info1.view.hidden = NO;
self.view.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that needed to make the transition between an `UIView` of a `UITabBarController` and a new `UIView`. The code goes to a button's `IBAction` which exists in one of the `UIView`s of the `UITabBarController`.

```
//initialize the app delegate

AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// get the view that's currently showing

UIView *currentView = self.view;

// get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view view

UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];
// remove the current view and replace with mynewView1
[currentView removeFromSuperview];

//assign the new view to the viewcontroller1. It is the first uiviewcontroller of the uitabbarcontroller. My uitabbarcontroller consists of five uiviewcontrollers in my project. The button exists in the first viewcontroller1 this is why i am assigning the new view to the viewcontroller1. If the button was pressed from the secondviewcontroller (viewcontroller2) of my uitabbarcontroller i will assign the new view to the secondviewcontroller (viewcontroller2) and so on...
appDelegate.viewController1=[[MyMessages alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMessages" bundle:nil];

//add it to the window
[theWindow addSubview:appDelegate.viewController1.view];

// set up an animation for the transition between the views
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

Thanks for you help! I have been trying this for more than a day to achieve it. I hope it will help someone with the same problem.